# how can I stylish non matched rows?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to stylish in red color every row that doesnt match to my settings , but I somehow it doesn't work . I tried to add `if-else`, but it doesnt work either on this one . how can I fix this? I just want to say if the words doesnt match then color red if not green or whatever

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var keywords = ['aslr', 'ida pro', 'gdb', 'windbg', 'immunity debugger', 'boofuzz', 'peach fuzzer', 'winafl', 'python', 'assembly', 'penetration testing', 'exploits', 'metasploit', 'metasploit framework', 'ethical hacker', 'pentest', 'computer security', 'hacking', 'oscp', 'osce', 'osee', 'penetration testing', 'offensive security', 'mitre att&ck', 'vulnerability research', 'vulnerability researcher', 'fuzzing', 'clang', 'llvm', 'address sanitizer', 'afl', 'fuzzers','penetration tester']
    var job_title = ['penetration tester','penetration testing', 'offensive security', 'vulnerability researcher','software','security','developer','ethical hacker','cyberSécurité','threat','it Security','application security','information security','security engineer','product security','cyber security','software engineer','security analyst','consultant cyber sécurité','ingénieur cybersécurité','penetration test consultant','Penetrationstestare']
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/index_get_data",
            "dataType": "json",
            "dataSrc": "jobs",
            "contentType":"application/json"
        },
        columnDefs: [{
            targets: 0,
            render: function (data) {
              if (job_title.some(word => data.includes(word)))
                return data
              else
                return data
            }
        },{
            targets: 4,
            render: function (data) {
              if (keywords.some(word => data.includes(word)))
                return "<span class='label label-success'>FOUND</span>";
              else 
                return  "<span class='label label-danger'>NOT_FOUND</span>";

            }
        },{
          targets: 5,
            render: function (data) {
                return '<a href="'+data+'">Link</a>'
            }
        }],
        "columns": [
            {"data": "job_title"},
            {"data": "company"},
            {"data": "city"},
            {"data": "date"},
            {"data": "job_description"},
            {"data": "url"},
        ],
        rowCallback: function( row, data ) {
          let matches = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < job_title.length; i += 1) {
            if (data.job_title.indexOf(job_title[i]) == -1) {
              matches++;
            }else{
              $(row).css({
                    'background-color': '#dff0d8'
                });
            }
          }
        }
    });
    setInterval( function () {
        table.ajax.reload( null, false );
    }, 30000 );
} );
```

````
if(matches){
  ... 
}else{
  ...
}```
````

Comment: Please add more code so that people can understand how your logic works and where the problem might be

Comment: update it ,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [CreateRow](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) function

```
var matches = [];

createdRow:function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
    matches[dataindex] = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < job_title.length; i += 1) {
        if (data.job_title.indexOf(job_title[i]) == -1) {
            matches[dataindex]++;
        }else{
            $(row).css({
                'background-color': '#dff0d8'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

if you want `if condition` should be execute after data loaded
so you should use [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/48103/callback-function-every-time-new-data-is-completely-loaded)

```
"drawCallback": function( settings ) {
   //if(matches[index]).....
}
```